# amstex: operator definition error

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I can't understand why the following code give me an error

```
\input amstex.tex
$\mathop{\rm arctg}(x)$
\bye
```

Thus, the input does not work with my macros that include the use of \rm, \mathop, etc., instructions.

Error:

```
! AmS-TeX error: Use \rm only in text.
\err@ #1->\errmessage {AmS-TeX error: #1}
\rm ...\Err@ {Use \string \rm \space only in text}
                                                  \else \tenrm \fi
l.3 $\mathop{\rm arctg}(x)$`
```

Comment: With `amstex` you should use `\roman`, `\italic`, `\bold` or `\slanted` for the corresponding fonts in math mode; so `\mathop{\roman{arctg}}` would work, although `\operatorname{arctg}` is better. As an aside, I know that "arctg" is traditional in Italy, but "arctan" is the international name (and the one defined by ISO regulations).

Comment: @egreg: I can't resist mentioning that "arctg" is traditional in France too, but hand-held calculators have initiated thirty years ago a slow but constant decline, much to my dispair.

Comment: @jfbu I prefer "arctan", to be honest. And also "sin", while in Italy it's traditional to use "sen".

Comment: @egreg it's not "arctan" which I dislike but the way it has raised to pre-eminence. I must be deeply conservative. Actually I am, I guess.

Comment: @egreg "sen" has a more sensual look than "sin"... ok, sorry, and apologies to the OP for this digression.

Answer (score 8):

for a number of reasons, ams-tex handles fonts differently in math than in text, and `\rm` has been defined to be a text-only font, resulting in the error

```
! AmS-TeX error: Use \rm only in text.
```

the expected way to handle an operator name in ams-tex is this:

```
$\operatorname{arctg}(x)$
```

where the roman (upright) font is automatic.